# vb.net arguments / command line in application

Tags: vb.net

I want to create my own command line.(as windows application, not prompt)
Example: `-f {filepath} -d {filename}` in textbox1

```
-f C://Windows/Users/Myname/Documents -d junk.exe
```

so it must filter the filepath and filename
so it becomes this `my.computer.filesystem.delete("C://Windows/Users/Myname/Documents", "junk.exe")`

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function to get the value of your desired parameter (the parameter name must include the '-' sign.)

```
Public Function GetParameter(input As String, param As String) As String
    Dim cmdargs As New List(Of String)
    For Each item As Match In Regex.Matches(input, """(\\""|[^""])*?""|[^ ]+")
        If item.ToString()(0) = """" And item.ToString()(item.ToString.Length - 1) = """" Then
            cmdargs.Add(item.ToString().Remove(0, 1).Remove(item.ToString.Length - 2, 1))
        Else
            cmdargs.Add(item.ToString())
        End If
    Next
    Return cmdargs(cmdargs.ToList().LastIndexOf(param) + 1)
End Function
```

If you use this function as `GetParameter("-f")` and your command-line arguments are
`-f C://Windows/Users/Myname/Documents -d junk.exe` then you will get `C://Windows/Users/Myname/Documents` as the output. Now if your command line has a space, you could enclose it within double quotes to avoid it being interpreted as 'multiple arguments'.

Now in an event-handling method (maybe a button click), you can use :-

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.Delete(GetParameter(TextBox1.Text, "-f"), GetParameter(TextBox1.Text, "-d"))
```

... to get the job done. Hope it helps :-). If you have questions, please comment below. **Updated**

Comment: Thank you for this!! but the commandline is in textbox1.text, not in the cmd prompt. how do I code it, to get it of the textbox?

Comment: i can't see the edit you made? sorry i really appriciate you for help and the others. Im not that good at coding, that's why i use vb.net. When i've got in textbox1 the line `"-d hello" ` and i click on button1 `MsgBox(GetParameter("-d"))` it gives me `C:\Users\Kennen\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe`

Comment: oh the edit is not showing up. wait i'll try once more a little while after.

Comment: Youuurreee... Welcome!

Comment: for your knowledge, the regex part is to imitate actual command line string decoding behavior.

Comment: to be honest. I don't understand anything of the code. In my app i've credit to you :)

Comment: no problem. but understanding the code will certainly help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your command line parameters this way:

```
Dim arguments As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

I found this on MSDN.

Comment: but how do i filter the text after `-f` or `-d` ?

Comment: you will get an array with ALL your parameters, so the first will be -f, the second will contain your foldername, the third will contain -d and so on. A loop through all arguments is needed (foreach ...), in this loop you analyze whatever you like

Comment: You may want to do a for...next loop instead of foreach... since foreach... doesn't guarantee it'll process in the correct order.  So something like For i as Int32 = 0 to arguments.Count - 1 ... <something with arguments(i) ... Next.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx  "If your code depends on traversing a collection in a particular order, a For Each...Next loop isn't the best choice, unless you know the characteristics of the enumerator object the collection exposes."

Comment: I dont get it. I just keeping this error: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of string'